# Как очистить окно вывода (Run Window) кодом на Python?

Tags: python, консоль, pycharm

**Как кодом на Python очистить окно вывода (Run Window)? Пишу в PyCharm.**

*Перепробовал разные варианты из интернета, но ничего не работает.*

```
from os import system

print("Консоль все еще заполнена текстом.")
system('cls') # оставляет мусор
```

[image: Подробнее на скриншоте]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27241268/clear-pycharm-run-window

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вы заметите то в консоль пайчарма всё таки выводится какой - то символ - это символ отчистки консоли. Т.к. пайчарм создан для отладки программ, а не для их запуска он выводит этот символ, а не отчищает консоль, это может помочь обнаружить баги в сложных приложениях. Если вы сохраните вашу программу и запустите при помощи питона консоль действительно отчистится. Если вы создадите .exe файл и выложите его на обозрение сообщества, у всех она тоже будет отчищаться.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так что если вам нужно (по специфическим причинам) что бы консоль пайчарма отчищалась, сделайте так, как посоветовал [SKIP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27241268/clear-pycharm-run-window) - через pyautogui.
Или проще `print("\n" * 99999)`

Но тогда будьте готовы к тому что обнаружить многие проблемы станет труднее.